# How to format data to algolia

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, algolia

I'm learning How to use Algolia and I have a few questions.

I have the table FreightDriver, which has a relationship `one to many` with the table Truck

```
id: ID!
name: String!
email: String!
phoneNumber: String!
cities: [String!]!
state: String!
country: String!
picture: String
trucks: [Truck] @connection(keyName: "byFreightDriver", fields: ["id"])
```

Then, the table Truck, which has a relationship `one to one` with the table FreightDriver, and another table, which is Box `one to one` as well

```
id: ID!
freightDriverId: ID!
boxId: ID!
brand: String!
model: String!
yearModel: Int!
// and more fields
freightDriver: FreightDriver @connection(fields: ["freightDriverId"])
box: Box @connection(fields: ["boxId"])
```

and the table Box:

```
id: ID!
type: String!
width: Float!
height: Float!
depth: Float!
```

I want to find trucks based on the state and city of the FreightDrivers, and also (if the user needs it), find based on the type of box and brand or model of a truck (just as an example).

Example find by state and city of a FreightDriver:

```
{
  "data": {
    "freightDriversByState": {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Andrés Montoya",
          "cities": [
            "GUADALAJARA"
          ],
          "state": "JALISCO",
          "country": "MX",
          "trucks": {
            "items": [
              {
                "brand": "chevrolet",
                "model": "12",
                "yearModel": 2020,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Ganadera",
                  "width": 1,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 3
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "chevrolet",
                "model": "12",
                "yearModel": 2020,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (abierta)",
                  "width": 12,
                  "height": 12,
                  "depth": 12
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "chevrolet",
                "model": "12",
                "yearModel": 2020,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (abierta)",
                  "width": 12,
                  "height": 12,
                  "depth": 12
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "chevrolet",
                "model": "Semi",
                "yearModel": 2020,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (abierta)",
                  "width": 1,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 3
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "chevrolet",
                "model": "12",
                "yearModel": 2020,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (abierta)",
                  "width": 1,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 3
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "chevrolet",
                "model": "12",
                "yearModel": 2020,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Volcadora",
                  "width": 1,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 3
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "hola",
                "model": "12",
                "yearModel": 12,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Plataforma",
                  "width": 1,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 3
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "Ford",
                "model": "12",
                "yearModel": 2020,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (abierta)",
                  "width": 1,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "dasdas",
                "model": "12",
                "yearModel": 12231,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Grúa",
                  "width": 1,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 3
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "Tesla",
                "model": "Semi",
                "yearModel": 2020,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (abierta)",
                  "width": 4,
                  "height": 4,
                  "depth": 2
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Roberto mendez",
          "cities": [
            "GUADALAJARA"
          ],
          "state": "JALISCO",
          "country": "MX",
          "trucks": {
            "items": []
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Fletes Jalisco Sa de Cv ",
          "cities": [
            "GUADALAJARA"
          ],
          "state": "JALISCO",
          "country": "MX",
          "trucks": {
            "items": [
              {
                "brand": "Ford",
                "model": "F-450",
                "yearModel": 2018,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (cerrada)",
                  "width": 2.7,
                  "height": 2.5,
                  "depth": 4.5
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "Hiundai",
                "model": "H100",
                "yearModel": 2009,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (abierta)",
                  "width": 2.3,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 4
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "Hiundai",
                "model": "H100",
                "yearModel": 2020,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (abierta)",
                  "width": 2.35,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 3
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "Ford",
                "model": "F-450",
                "yearModel": 2018,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (cerrada)",
                  "width": 2.7,
                  "height": 2.2,
                  "depth": 3
                }
              },
              {
                "brand": "Ford",
                "model": "F-450",
                "yearModel": 2004,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (abierta)",
                  "width": 2.5,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 3
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Cotransport",
          "cities": [
            "GUADALAJARA"
          ],
          "state": "JALISCO",
          "country": "MX",
          "trucks": {
            "items": [
              {
                "brand": "Chevrolet",
                "model": "CX-5",
                "yearModel": 2019,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (cerrada)",
                  "width": 4,
                  "height": 3,
                  "depth": 4
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Andrés",
          "cities": [
            "EL LIMÓN",
            "MAGDALENA",
            "SANTA MARÍA DEL ORO",
            "GUADALAJARA",
            "ETZATLÁN"
          ],
          "state": "JALISCO",
          "country": "MX",
          "trucks": {
            "items": [
              {
                "brand": "chevrolet",
                "model": "12",
                "yearModel": 2020,
                "box": {
                  "type": "Seca (abierta)",
                  "width": 1,
                  "height": 2,
                  "depth": 3
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But, if I want to find using the state and city of a freight driver, the type of box and the model or brand of a truck, that's where the problem comes, because I'm using Dynamodb and this one does not have relationships, so, it's a little bit tricky to get the exact data. That's why I'd like to use Algolia, but how do I format the data for Algolia in this case? What do I need to do? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, here's the answer https://discourse.algolia.com/t/how-to-format-data-to-algolia/10897